# How to scrape div class that is nested

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

**Hi, I have a local html file containing messages from a chat:**

```
<div class="body">
<div class="pull_right date details" title="01.01.2022 01:01:01">
01:01
       </div>
<div class="from_name">
XYZ
       </div>
<div class="reply_to details">
In reply to <a href="#go_to_message23" onclick="return GoToMessage(747)">this message</a>
</div>
<div class="text">
Eat some chocolate
       </div>
```

**Now I want to create a df showing certain information for each message. E.g I extracted the name of the user writing the message with:**

```
# doc.select('div[id]')[2].select_one('.from_name').text.strip()

messages = doc.select('div[id]')

for message in messages:
    print('---')
    try:
        print([message.select_one('.from_name').text.strip()])
    except:
        print("Couldn't find a name")
```

**But I can't figure out how to extract the date the message was sent. Can somebody help? Thanks**

Answer (score 0):

Simply select your element and call its attribute `title` to extract the value:

```
select_one('div[title]').get('title')
```

###### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html='''
<div class="body">
<div class="pull_right date details" title="01.01.2022 01:01:01">
01:01
       </div>
<div class="from_name">
XYZ
       </div>
<div class="reply_to details">
In reply to <a href="#go_to_message23" onclick="return GoToMessage(747)">this message</a>
</div>
<div class="text">
Eat some chocolate
       </div>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

data = []

for e in soup.select('div.body'):
    data.append({
        'date':e.select_one('div[title]').get('title'),
        'name':e.select_one('div.from_name').contents[0].strip(),
        'text':e.select_one('div.text').text.strip(),
    })
data
```

###### Output

```
 [{'date': '01.01.2022 01:01:01', 'name': 'XYZ', 'text': 'Eat some chocolate'}]
```

---

You could simply turn your results into a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Output

```
                  date name                text
0  01.01.2022 01:01:01  XYZ  Eat some chocolate
```

Comment: Thanks. I had to modify it a bit because not every message has a time stamp etc. Because "meta text" like "The owner of the chat added person xyz to the chat" is also counted as a message in the file. But now it works.